# Integral of an area function interpretation

Tags: calculus

When calculating volume of 3d bodies,we deduce formulas such as $\int A dr$ where $A$ is an area function.Now if $\int$ is interpreted as area,what does the integral of an area function mean?Also when calculating arc lengths,we aren't adding areas.But when we get the expression $\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$ we manipulate $\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx$.Then we take integral.It seems we are adding some strips of area of a function $\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$.But this interpretation of area doesn't make sense to me as summing arc length is not area.Could you please explain how to interpret the above two scenarios.

Comment: I am very ignorant in this area.  Also, I like the idea that you are trying to develop your intuition.  My instinct is that although it is a good intuitive-crutch to construe $\int$ as area in *beginning* Calculus problems, that sort of intuition will lead to trouble with the more advanced problems, such as arc length or volume.

Comment: The alternative interpretation is that $\int$ is nothing more than the inverse of the derivative, and so it can be proven that various formulas involving $\int$ hold when computing (for example) volume or arc length.  Here, I am obviously revealing my ignorance, since my experience is limited to Reimann integration.

Comment: The square root implies the use of Pythagorean theorem. You're adding lengths, not areas.

Comment: I know that,i wanted to know the intuitive interpretation of them.

Comment: Intuitively, it is the $x$-axis being pulled into a curve. For the $x-$axis, $dy/dx=0$, and you get the standard integral. If it is not the $x-$axis, you are adding infinitesimal line segments from each point $(x_i,y_i)$ to $(x_i+\Delta x, y_i+\Delta x)$ whose length is $\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$ and then multiplying by the "height" of the function ($dx$ or $dy$) to get infinitesimal areas.